# Wavelength limited resolution

Tags: visible-light, diffraction, telescopes

I've read through answers to similar questions, and I haven't been able to find a satisfying answer. I've heard it said that in order to make out something, you need to use light with a wavelength at least as large as the object. In what way can you mathematically derive this heuristic?

Moreover, does this apply *generally*? The other day I was thinking in the context of sound waves and how fruit bats use them to resolve insects- is this a reason why they use high frequencies?

Comment: No, one does not need light with a wavelength as small as the objects that one wants to image. Look at super-resolution microscopy for strong counterexamples: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-resolution_microscopy. That fruit-bats are using ultrasound has probably as much to do with the size of their ears as it has with the size of their prey. Efficient emission and reception of sound is only possible when the emitter and receiver are of the same size as the wavelength. The scatterers could be smaller and may still be detectable, but the sensitivity of the bat's ears would be insufficient.

Comment: @CuriousOne Then what is the regime where this holds? For microscopes? Is this because of that formula for diffraction limited resolution? This is the reason they give for electron microscopes being useful, correct?

Comment: It doesn't hold in any regime. That resolution is a simple function of wavelength is one of those physical myths that are based on naive 19th century arguments that made some sense for visual microscopic observations which had to take the human eye's limited ability to distinguish different levels of brightness into account. As soon as one can do photon counting with CCD cameras and image processing and we have fluorescing dyes and laser excitation in play, the naive arguments simply don't hold.

Comment: @CuriousOne But then why are electron microscopes useful?

Comment: Also backing up a bit, where can I read about the efficiency sound transmission based on emitter and receiver size?

Comment: Like I said, the naive theory doesn't hold in any regime, one can see single atoms with light easily and resolve features that are significantly smaller than a wavelength, but that doesn't mean that the resolution is infinite. The resolution is still limited, it's just more complicated than the 19th century Rayleigh criterion suggests. Electron microscopes also "see" things that light can't, e.g. they can be used to measure elemental composition. Maybe I should write an answer... I'll think about it.

Comment: If you find the time, please do.